# CodeIgniter form helper - nothing happens when clicking on submit

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, action

I want to integrate Bootstrap form with CodeIgniter and I followed the documentation (https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html), but when I click to submit the form nothing happens. Can you tell me where I do it wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
 $form = array(
'name' => "SentMessage",
'id' => "contactForm"
 );
 $email = array(
'name' => 'email',
'class' => "form-control",
'placeholder'=>"Email",
'id' => "email",
'required data-validation-required-message'=>"Please, enter your email."
 );
 $password = array(
'name' => 'password',
'class' => "form-control",
'placeholder' => "Password",
'id' => "password",
'required data-validation-required-message'=>"Please, enter your password."
 );
 $cpassword = array(
'class' => "form-control",
'placeholder' => "Confirm password",
'id' => "cpassword",
'required data-validation-required-message' => "Please, confirm your         password"
 );
 $submit = array(
'name' => 'signup_submit',
'value' => 'Submit',
'class' => 'btn btn-default'
 );

 ?>

<?php echo form_open('login_register/signup_validation', $form)?>
<div class="row control-group">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
        <label>Email</label>
        <?php echo form_input($email); ?>
        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row control-group">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
        <label>Password</label>
        <?php echo form_password($password); ?>
        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row control-group">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <?php echo form_password($cpassword); ?>
        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="success"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
        <?php echo form_submit($submit);?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php form_close();?>
```

Comment: Have you include $this->load->helper('form'); to your controller?

Comment: remove `$form` from `<?php echo form_open('login_register/signup_validation')?>` and try

Comment: Yes, I autoload my form helper. And for the second answer - even if I remove the $form array - still nothing happens.

Comment: @YasenIvanov Have you checked generated HTML ?

Comment: @jagad89 , without the HTML it works, but why is not working with it? Everything seems in place?

Comment: @YasenIvanov I mean, Have you check that every html tags are properly opened and closed  ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. **check** if you have **initialize helper like URL and FORM** or not. Also, make sure login_register/**signup_validation** method is present in controller.

Comment: I autoload my URL and FORM helpers. I have controller set up and it works without the Bootstrap HTML, but I can't figure why.

Comment: All I can say is the code you provided here is perfect and it should work when both url and form helper are called. Please provide the code, Bootstrap HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

I took your code as-is, put it in a CI view that is in a CI/Bootstrap environment that I know is working, and it worked perfectly. The only thing I added was loading the form helper at the top of the page and I put in a print_r statement for debugging. I also changed your submit URL to point back to itself so I could see if the submit worked, and it did. You can see it here http://home.toolzilla.net/test

I don't see how Bootstrap could affect this, but the test site is a fully working Codeigniter/Bootstrap environment and you can see the set-up here https://bitbucket.org/greco-roamin/toolzilla

Here is the exact code in the test page, which is identical to yours except the changes I mentioned above.

```
<?php
$this->load->helper('form');
print_r($this->input->post());

 $form = array(
'name' => "SentMessage",
'id' => "contactForm"
 );
 $email = array(
'name' => 'email',
'class' => "form-control",
'placeholder'=>"Email",
'id' => "email",
'required data-validation-required-message'=>"Please, enter your email."
 );
 $password = array(
'name' => 'password',
'class' => "form-control",
'placeholder' => "Password",
'id' => "password",
'required data-validation-required-message'=>"Please, enter your password."
 );
 $cpassword = array(
'class' => "form-control",
'placeholder' => "Confirm password",
'id' => "cpassword",
'required data-validation-required-message' => "Please, confirm your         password"
 );
 $submit = array(
'name' => 'signup_submit',
'value' => 'Submit',
'class' => 'btn btn-default'
 );

 ?>

<?php echo form_open('test', $form)?>
<div class="row control-group">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
        <label>Email</label>
        <?php echo form_input($email); ?>
        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row control-group">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
        <label>Password</label>
        <?php echo form_password($password); ?>
        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row control-group">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <?php echo form_password($cpassword); ?>
        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="success"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
        <?php echo form_submit($submit);?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php form_close();?>
```